# changing on click to on page load

Tags: jquery, function, click, fadein, pageload

I found this jquery script for delaying and fading in list items on pressing/clicking a button (works great); how do I change this to run on page load rather than on click please?

```
<script>        
function fadeItem() {
    $('#thisimage ul li:hidden:first').delay(25).fadeIn(fadeItem);
}

$('button').click(fadeItem);
$('#thisimage li').hide();
</script>
```

my list items are within the #thisimage div

Answer (score 3):

Remove `$('button').click(fadeItem)` and add :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  fadeItem();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$('button').click(fadeItem)` to

```
$(function(){ fadeItem() });
```

see this : http://api.jquery.com/ready/